# Making Object Reappear

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have set up a point system in my side scroller game. Every time a circle is touched by the main moving sprite, a few points are added to the point counter and that circle disappears. I need help making the coin reappears back in its original place, after the main sprite dies and returns to the starting position.
Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mittank1701/7qd5v2hp/18/).

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var positionX = 100.0;
var positionY = 175.0;
var velocityX = 4.0;
var velocityY = 0.0;
var gravity = 0.5;
var onGround = false;
var deaths = 0;
var points = 0;

var color = "#0095DD";
var circlex = "350";
var circley = "100";



window.addEventListener("mousedown", StartJump, false);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", EndJump, false);

Loop();

function StartJump()
{
    if(onGround)
    {
        velocityY = -12.0;
        onGround = false;
    }
}

function EndJump()
{
    if(velocityY < -6.0)
        velocityY = -6.0;
}

function Loop()
{
    Update();
    Render();
    window.setTimeout(Loop, 30);    
}

function Update()
{
    velocityY += gravity;
    positionY += velocityY;
    positionX += velocityX;

    // Collision Detection //
    if ((positionX > 239 && positionX < 292 && positionY > 145) || (positionX > 439 && positionX < 492 && positionY > 145) || (positionX > 639 && positionX < 692 && positionY > 145) || (positionX > 839 && positionX < 892 && positionY > 145) || (positionX > 839 && positionX < 892 && positionY > 50 && positionY < 100))
    {
        positionX = 50;
        deaths++;
    }

    if(positionY > 175.0)
    {
        positionY = 175.0;
        velocityY = 0.0;
        onGround = true;
    }

    if(positionX < 10 || positionX > 1000)
    velocityX *= -1;      

   if(positionX > 339 && positionX < 372 && positionY > 110 && positionY < 150)
    {
    points++;
    circlex = -10;
    circley = -10;
    }
}

function drawSquare1() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(250, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawCircle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circlex, circley, 7, 7, 500);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawSquare2() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(450, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawSquare3() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(650, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawSquare5() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(850, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawSquare4() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(850, 50, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawDeaths() {
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Deaths: "+deaths, 8, 20);
}

function drawPoints() {
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Points: "+points, 8, 50);
}

function Render()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    drawCircle();
    drawSquare1();
    drawSquare2();
    drawSquare3();
    drawSquare4();
    drawSquare5();
    drawDeaths();
    drawPoints();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,175);
    ctx.lineTo(1000,175);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(positionX - 10, positionY - 20);
    ctx.lineTo(positionX + 10, positionY - 20);
    ctx.lineTo(positionX + 10, positionY);
    ctx.lineTo(positionX - 10, positionY);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke(); 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply move the location of the coin/blue dot when the player collides with it.

```
if(positionX > 339 && positionX < 372 && positionY > 110 && positionY < 150)
{
  points++;
  circlex += 50;
}
```

However, you should become more familiar with object-oriented programming and use this as it is ideal for objects in a game such as players and coins. I'm not  sure how much you know about objects in javascript, but you should check out [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-objectorientedjs/) article on object-oriented design within a javascript game

Comment: I'll definitely check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

Reset the circle position after a death...

```
// Collision Detection //
if ((positionX > 239 && positionX < 292 && positionY > 145) || (positionX > 439 && positionX < 492 && positionY > 145) || (positionX > 639 && positionX < 692 && positionY > 145) || (positionX > 839 && positionX < 892 && positionY > 145) || (positionX > 839 && positionX < 892 && positionY > 50 && positionY < 100))
{
    positionX = 50;
    deaths++;
    circlex = 350;
    circley = 100;
}
```

And ensure that points are not added if the circle isn't there...

```
if(positionX > 339 && positionX < 372 && positionY > 110 && positionY < 150 &&
        circlex != -10 && circley != -10)
{
    points++;
    circlex = -10;
    circley = -10;
}
```

You can see that I've updated the logic so that the circle is only moved and points added, if it's not in its "disappeared" location.

Nice, fun, little game :)

Comment: Thanks! I just started learning JS so I'm just starting to understand some of these simple concepts and the logic behind them, this helped a ton.